# Using Smart IP (or similar) on cached pages

Tags: 7, hooks

I would like to use the [Smart IP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_ip) module for IP detection; however, it runs its detection in `hook_init()`, which does not run on cached pages. I am not married to the module.

I have tried to pull out the guts of the detection and put it into `hook_boot()`, but there are too many dependencies to do this efficiently. I have it working in `hook_exit()`, but I am concerned that trying to store the detected country in a session will fail. Also, I would be unable to include the Smart IP'S JavaScript in `hook_exit()`, since the page is already rendered when it is added.

What are the other ways to get IP detection that sets a session variable on all cached pages?